# jQuery click through array, change 3 items on page

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, infinite-loop

I have an array of objects with values for a link, an image tag and a title.

```
var array = [
{ 'link': 'link0', 'src': 'page-0.jpg', 'title': 'Title 0' },
{ 'link': 'link1', 'src': 'page-1.jpg', 'title': 'Title 1' },
{ 'link': 'link2', 'src': 'page-2.jpg', 'title': 'Title 2' },
{ 'link': 'link3', 'src': 'page-3.jpg', 'title': 'Title 3' },
{ 'link': 'link4', 'src': 'page-4.jpg', 'title': 'Title 4' }
];
```

My page has three images with the titles below each:

```
[Title 4], [Title 0], [Title 1]
```

The last array item will be in slot one, the first array item in slot two and the second item in slot three

When a user clicks the left or right arrows I need to loop back and forth through the array, changing the three slots on the page like so:

```
[4], [0], [1] (Start view)
[0], [1], [2]
[1], [2], [3]
[2], [3], [4]
[3], [4], [0]
[4], [0], [1] (End view)
```

Anyone know how I could do this? Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried ? Why have you tagged this as infinite-loop are you facing any problems ? This question has nothing to do with jquery or in its current form.

Comment: I just can't figure out the logic to loop through on click while updating three areas on the page. I have removed the jQuery tag.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the requirements!

Each time a user clicks a button, you need to increment or decrement the value(s) that reference the array. Those values will need to be stored somewhere - You could use three variables (global), if you'd like. For this demo, I assigned them to a "state" object:

```
var state = {
    start_a: 4,
    start_b: 0,
    start_c: 1
}
```

The next part is the logic to increments/decrements our values. My code isn't anything special and could probably be cleaned up (or optimized), but here's what I wrote:

```
function click(dir) {
    var key;

    // Loop the state object to get appropriate values
    for (key in state) {

        // Based on direction, we need to update values that are 0 or 4 (first/last)
        // so not to break inner/outer bound
        if (dir === -1) {
            if (state[key] === 0) {
                state[key] = 4;
            } else {
                state[key] += dir;
            }
        } else {
            if (state[key] === 4) {
                state[key] = 0;
            } else {
                state[key] += dir;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return state object
    return state;
}
```

Finally, we need to pass to our increment/decrement function the direction. For that, I binded two event handlers and just pass 1/-1.

```
document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var data = click(-1);
    updateValues(data);
});

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var data = click(1);
    updateValues(data);
});
```

Here's a fiddle with a demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/uL8fb/

Hope this helps!